# Go to Definition in Python Microsoft Extension is not working in modules

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have installed

- Python 2.7
- Visual Studio Code 1.471.
- Python Extension 2020.6.91350

While Go to definitions works within same module, but if we import some other module, Go to definition don't work

Any idea what can be solution for this ?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues Report to the developers.

Comment: Thanks @LexLi for informing

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: Your language server might not be opening up properly because vscode version is not up to date. This goes to all languages

If your symptoms include

1. Type `>Python: Show output` in vscode console
2. Restart vscode and open any python file
3. In the output if you see any line saying something close to `Error: cant't start language server because vscode version low`

You need your vscode updated to latest version.

Answer (score 0):

In my case even though i had Python extension i was missing Pylance extension, after manually installing it jump to definition is working as intended